# updateNote API stopped working after collaborative editing release

Tags: evernote

The `updateNote` API completely stopped working for me after the collaborative editing release.

I use the Python API library:
git://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/

This call completely stopped updating the note with new content:
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote

I do not see any errors at all; it is just the note contents stay the same.
Did you see similar issues, any ways to resolve them?

Answer (score 2):

same problem with SDK version 3.  The updateNote method in the NoteStore class works shows as successful and even shows an update to the content via the API but in the web and local clients you can can see the updated content in the preview pain but the note in the main window is not updated.

Basically the API is no longer able to update notes and have them rendered on any client.